# How to reduce bottom margin in CPCL command?

Tags: java, android, printing, zebra-printers

I tried this command:

```
            //COUPON TICKET...
            mPrinter.sendCommand("! 0 200 200 560 1");
            mPrinter.sendCommand("CENTER");
            mPrinter.sendCommand("TEXT 5 0 48 30 ALTA CITTA");
            mPrinter.sendCommand("TEXT 5 0 48 60 SURFACE PAY PARKING");
            mPrinter.sendCommand("LEFT");
            mPrinter.sendCommand("TEXT 5 0 0 120 Ticket#: " + globalvars.get("uid"));
            mPrinter.sendCommand("TEXT 5 0 0 160 Date Issued: " + globalvars.get("dateToday") + " / " + globalvars.get("dateTimeToday"));
            mPrinter.sendCommand("TEXT 5 0 0 200 Valid Until: " + globalvars.get("dateUntil"));
            mPrinter.sendCommand("CENTER");
            mPrinter.sendCommand("TEXT 5 0 0 270 ********************************************");
            mPrinter.sendCommand("TEXT 5 0 0 320 CONSUMABLE COUPON");
            mPrinter.sendCommand("TEXT 5 0 0 350" + "Php " + globalvars.get("amount") + ".00");
            mPrinter.sendCommand("BARCODE 128 3 1 75 0 400 "+globalvars.get("checkDigit"));
            mPrinter.sendCommand("TEXT 5 0 0 480 "+globalvars.get("checkDigit"));
            mPrinter.sendCommand("WAIT 24");
            mPrinter.sendCommand("FORM");
            mPrinter.sendCommand("PRINT");
```

I tried to remove "FORM Command" and removes the margin but i can`t use "WAIT Command". Thanks in advance!

Comment: by quick look at the `wait` and `form` command in docs it looks like the `form` is necessary. Also it looks that, both of this commands are unrelated to the margin you get, therefore other commands must be manipulating the design of the output. Please try providing the more information, e.g. what is error output after removing the above, what is the current look of the barcode/bill you print.

Comment: Thanks for this comments. Much appreciated.